# How a system dll(like kernel32.dll) is signed

Tags: windows

I have a doubt related to digital signatures.
I understand that, if an executable or dll is singed with some signature, I will be able to see "Digital Signatures" tab when I right click on the file.

But when I right click on `kernel32.dll`, it doesn't show me this tab("Digital Signatures"), but I know that this file is signed by Microsoft.

This dll(`kernel32.dll`) has some references to `WinVerifyTrust`, which are not present in a regular digital signed exe or dll.

Can someone explain me how differently a system dll is signed than a regular dll? and what is `wintrust.dll` file?

I sign regular dll as below:

```
signtool sign /v /f  MySPC.pfx mydll.dll
```

But I am sure that system dll's are not signed this way. Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:http://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/01/11/the-case-of-the-missing-digital-signatures-tab/

There are 2 different ways to sign a PE file: by adding a digital signature to the PE file (embedded digital signature) or by adding a hash of the PE file to a security catalog file (filetype .CAT).

The Properties dialog of a file hosts a Digital Signatures tab when the PE file has an embedded digital signature.

But when a file is signed via a security catalog file, the Digital Signatures tab is not displayed.

About wintrust.dll : It provides the APIs to verify the trust in files, signature or certificates. e.g. WinVerifyTrust API.

Comment: Thank you so much explaining this. I am downloading WDK(Windows driver kit) to get signability tool, to be able to create catalog file. Let you know the results.

Comment: I could finally make my own dll and sign it as system dll's are singed.

Comment: These are the steps,   C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\x86\MakeCat.exe -v test.cdf       -- Create a catalog file. This catalog file contains hash of the test.dll
 
signtool sign /v /f MySPC.pfx /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll test.cat    -- sign the catalog file.
 
signtool catdb /v /u test.cat   --  add this catalog file in the cat file database of the system.        Now , you need to copy the dll file where other dll's(like kernel32.dll) are present and copy the lib where kernel32.lib is present.

Comment: nice to see your comment !! Thanks